# Batch text manipulation

Tags: batch-file, csv

Hello I am trying to manipulate a .csv file with batch  and then save it as a txt with a specific name it grabs from the .csv file.  Each file can be different lengths so I need to a go to EOF.  Also I have all the files in one folder and it is about 50 files.  Here is what the file looks like:

```html
FROM: 20.12 13:23
//Current Deck
"Constantine-6, Sacred Sanctuary-6, Zodiac Harbinger-6, Honorable Samurai-6, Tempest Citadel-6, Bolt Crag-6(2), Jyack-6, Serraco Sire-6, Stoneheart-6, Irrian Grafter-6"
//Owned Cards
Omega-1
Smog Tank-1
Smog Tank-4
Xeno Mothership-1
Apex-1(2)
Octane-1
```

I want it to look like below.

```html
//Current Deck: Constantine-6, Sacred Sanctuary-6, Zodiac Harbinger-6, Honorable Samurai-6, Tempest Citadel-6, Bolt Crag-6(2), Jyack-6, Serraco Sire-6, Stoneheart-6, Irrian Grafter-6
//Owned Cards
Omega-1
Smog Tank-1
Smog Tank-4
Xeno Mothership-1
Apex-1(2)
Octane-1
```

and then save it as the playername.

Help please?

Comment: Do you have a crystal ball we can use to determine the player name?

Comment: The player name will be the last line of the .csv file or I can make it the first line....Sorry for not stating that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir\t w o"
FOR %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\*.csv") DO (
 FOR %%r IN (cdeck ocards) DO SET "%%r="
 FOR /f "usebackqskip=1delims=" %%r IN ("%%a") DO (
  IF DEFINED ocards (ECHO(%%r) ELSE (
   IF DEFINED cdeck (SET ocards=Y&ECHO(//current Deck: %%~r) ELSE (
    SET cdeck=Y
   )
  )
 )
)>"%sourcedir%\%%~na.txt"

GOTO :EOF
```

Since you provide no clue as to how the data is to be processed, I have chosen to delete the first line, append the third to the second, adding the colon and removing the quotes and then reproduce verbatim the remaining lines.

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Each `.csv` file would be processed to `same name.txt`